# Does the game support cross-platform multiplayer?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I have a PS3 and my friend has a PS4. We both have Arkham Origins for our respective consoles. Can we play online together?

Answer (score 1):

Neither batmanarkhamorigins.com, wikipedia.org nor amazon.com list the PS4 as an available platform for Batman Arkham Origins.

Available platfoms are PS3, XBOX360, PC and WiiU. Between these, cross platform multiplayer is not possible.

If there ever should be a PS4 version (which I doubt, but there were rumours), PS3/PS4 multiplayer would be technically possible as announced by Sony, but would need to be especially implemented by the game developers (which I again highly doubt.)

You should check the truthfullness of your friends claims of having the PS4 version.